# Python: Creating multi dimensional array of multidimensional zero array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Hello I have the following question. I create zero arrays of dimension (40,30,80). Now I need 7*7*7 of these zero arrays in an array. How can I do this?
One of my matrices is created like this:

```
import numpy as np
zeroMatrix = np.zeros((40,30,80))
```

My first method was to put the zero matrices in a 7*7*7 list. But i want to have it all in a numpy array. I know that there is a way with structured arrays I think, but i dont know how. If i copy my 7*7*7 list with np.copy() it creates a numpy array with the given shape, but there must be a way to do this instantly, isnt there?

**EDIT**

Maybe I have to make my question clearer. I have a 7*7 list of my zero matrices. In a for loop all of that arrays will be modified. In another step, this tempory list is appended to an empty list which will have a length of 7 in the end ( So i append the 7*7 list 7 times to the empty list. In the end I have a 7*7*7 List of those matrices. But I think this will be better If I have a numpy array of these zero matrices from the beginning.

Comment: Please clarify this sentence "Now I need 7*7 of these zero arrays in a array."

Comment: `np.zeros((7, 7, 40, 30, 80))`?

Comment: `np.frompyfunc(zeroMatrix.copy, 0, 1)(np.empty((7, 7, 7), object))` gives an array of arrays.

Comment: exactly what i searched for! Thank you:) I would upvote it, but maybe you write it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building an array of same-shaped arrays is not well supported by numpy which prefers to create a maximum depth array of minimum depth elements instead.

It turns out that `numpy.frompyfunc` is quite useful in circumventing this tendency where it is unwanted.

In your specific case one could do:

```
result = np.frompyfunc(zeroMatrix.copy, 0, 1)(np.empty((7, 7, 7), object))
```

Indeed:

```
>>> result.shape
(7, 7, 7)
>>> result.dtype
dtype('O')
>>> result[0, 0, 0].shape
(40, 30, 80)
```